# Copy cells from one workbook into multiple workbooks excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have around 300 workbooks in the same folder, and i want to copy cell B19-B49 from 1 workbook into the rest of the 300 workbooks in the same folder. Is that possible in some clever way so I dont have to copy-paste through 300 different files?

Best regards

Comment: http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Loop%20Through%20Folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple PowerShell script to copy the value from the source file to the files in the destination directory.  Just replace the 5 variables at the top with your values:

```
$sourceFile = "c:\tmp\source.xlsx"
$destinationDirectory = "c:\tmp"
$sheetName = "Sheet1"
$rangeToCopyStart = "B19"
$rangeToCopyEnd = "B49"

#----------------------------------------------
# Open Excel source file
#----------------------------------------------

$excelApplication = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application                        
$excelWorkbook = $excelApplication.Workbooks.Open($sourceFile, 2, $True)
$excelWorksheet = $excelWorkbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)            

#----------------------------------------------
# Copy the cell value 
#----------------------------------------------

"Value to copy:" + $excelWorksheet.Range($rangeToCopyStart, $rangeToCopyEnd).Value2;
"From:" + $sourceFile;
$excelWorksheet.Range($rangeToCopyStart, $rangeToCopyEnd).Copy() | out-null;
$excelWorkbook.Close();                                                

#----------------------------------------------
# Get all Excel files from destination directory 
#----------------------------------------------

$Files = Get-ChildItem $destinationDirectory -Filter *.xlsx

Foreach ($Item in $Files) {

    $destinationFile = $Item.FullName

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Skip the source file if it's in the same directory 
    #----------------------------------------------


    If ($sourceFile.ToLower() -eq $destinationFile.ToLower())  { continue; }  

    $destinationWorkbook = $excelApplication.Workbooks.Open($destinationFile, 2, $False)       
    $destinationWorkSheet = $destinationWorkbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)                 

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Paste the value into the destination file
    #----------------------------------------------

    $destinationWorkSheet.Paste($destinationWorkSheet.Range($rangeToCopyStart, $rangeToCopyEnd)); 
    $destinationWorkbook.Close($True);  #save changes and close

    "Copied to: " + $destinationFile;
}


#----------------------------------------------
# Quit Excel and release the object
#----------------------------------------------

$excelApplication.Quit();
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelApplication) | out-null;
```

Comment: Im totally new to powershell, so please excuse my ignorance.
When running the script all it paste into the files are "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned " in cell B19.
Why is this? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: To avoid issues with execution policy, run the script in PowerShell ISE rather than PowerShell command line.  You can find it in the same place as the command line exe (e.g.  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0) and then once in the ISE click "New", paste the script, change your values and press F5 to run the script

Answer (score 0):

'Hi Below the code for your requirement...please note you can change the myextension as per your requirement..

Sub Button2_Click()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all workbooks in a user selected folder and perform a similar task

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

    'Optimize Macro Speed
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
      Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        With FldrPicker
          .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
          .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End With

    'In Case of Cancel
```

NextCode:
          myPath = myPath
          If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

```
    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
      myExtension = "*.xlsx"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
      myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
      Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
          Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
          wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)

        'Save and Close Workbook
          wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

        'Get next file name
          myFile = Dir
      Loop

    'Message Box when tasks are completed
      MsgBox "Task Complete!"
```

ResetSettings:
          'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can write vba module in source workbook that loops over files in target folder, opens it (with Workbooks.Open method), adds needed cells and saves.